# Regular expression for text between double square brackets, but NOT between hyphens

Tags: regex

I cant find a regular expression which works for my situation. I need to get all text between double square brackets, but which is NOT between hyphens. For example:

```
[[abc]] would get abc
[[-abc]] would get -abc 
[[abc-]] would get abc-
[[-abc-]] would get nothing
```

I have been able to almost get what I  want with:

```
\[\[(\-(.*?)\-)\]\]
```

but this expression returns the text between the double square brackets AND which is also between hyphens (I need it NOT being between hyphens)

Any help please?

Comment: Maybe `\[{2}(?!-\w+-]])(.*?)]]`? See https://regex101.com/r/p40FAc/1 and the green highlighted matched parts.

Comment: How is this question related to Java?

Comment: What about `[[a-bc-]]`?

Comment: I think `\[\[([^\[\]]+(?<!-[^\[\]]*-))\]\]` [might be more accurate](https://regexr.com/49p1k). I beleive Wiktor's solution [may not satisfy your conditions](https://regex101.com/r/p40FAc/2)

Comment: Pep, you should explain what you want to avoid matching inside the double brackets and what you want to match. If anything, then `\[{2}(?!-(?:(?!\[{2}).)*?-]])(.*?)]]` might be more accurate. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UhLlMy/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Agreed, more detail from Pep would be nice.

Comment: @LutzHorn Sorry for the confusion about tagging the question as Java... the thing is  the regular expression will be running in Java but could be related to any language... sorry

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your second solution is working perfectly. The first one isn't as [[-abc.10-]] is detecting it as correct (I suppose it's because of the dot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern is working for me:

```
(?!\[{2}\-[^(\-|\s)]*\-\]{2})\[{2}([^(?:\]{2})]*)\]{2}
```

Matching the pattern you **don't** want (`[[-foobar-]]`) is pretty easy, so this solution uses a negative look-ahead to ensure the following **doesn't** match that pattern, then grabs everything between double brackets as a capture group.

Test it out here: https://regex101.com/r/pxbwKo/2

Comment: What does `[^(\-|\s)]*` do here? And `[^(?:\]{2})]*`? You seem to confuse what character classes do in regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You likely know more about regex than I do. If there is an error, feel free to describe it or post your own answer.

Comment: I will when I'm at my desktop.